# Character floating after walking up higher terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to fix this but I can't find any tutorials for this. The problem is, if I walk the character on the higher terrain or anything that can be walk. The character will float once I leave on the higher terrain. I want something that the character will stays on the ground. The components that I used are character controller and capsule collider. Thanks in advance guys.

**PS**: The curves that you see is an object. Its not a bumpy/raised or painted height terrain.

The game will start with this position.
[image]

After walking on the higher object/terrain and walk back, it will look like this. It remains floating.
[image]

So far, this what I've tried but its not working.

```
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);

RaycastHit hitInfo;

LayerMask layer = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");

//cast ray
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, layer))
{
    //get where on the z axis our raycast hit the ground
    float z = hitInfo.point.z;

    //copy current position into temporary container
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;

    //change z to where on the z axis our raycast hit the ground
    pos.z = z;

    //override our position with the new adjusted position.
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: The `z` axis isn't the vertical axis in Unity. Also, why aren't you letting the physics engine deal with this using a Rigidbody component?

Comment: Does your character have a RigidBody component on it ? if it does then do you have gravity enabled ?

Comment: I've tried the RigidBody and the gravity is enabled but its not working.

Comment: If I add the RigidBody component, what properties will I modify or there's any code that I will add? What should I do guys?